# TriggerHandler() only generated on first element with ngClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I want to automatic click on my element, here is the code in my controller

```
setTimeout(function() {
    angular.element('.clickme').triggerHandler('click')
}, 300);
```

Here is the element which is supposed to open a form upon click on dynamic generated content:

```
<span class="cur clickme"  ng-click="openForm()" >dyanamic generated content </span>
```

The problem is, that it's only triggered for the first generated element, not its child element . I want to show the current generated element which should be click automatically to show a form. right now its showing only first elements form.

Comment: you can directly call the `openForm()` function, help me understand the case where you want to trigger click to call the openForm function..

Comment: use `.on` to bind click event to dynamically generated elements using class , avoid using `timeout`

Comment: .on not working

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','.clickme',function(){ // trigger click here })` @Animay . you can share a sample repo in fiddle/plunker .

Comment: @Animay - check if this is what your are expecting - http://jsfiddle.net/fgta2e0w/4/